# How do you say "online" and "offline" in Latin?

Tags: contemporary-latin, new-latin, modern-life, neologism

Good day!

How would you go about saying the expression "online" or "offline" in Latin? Maybe something like Portuguese *Conectado* and *Desconectado* (connected and disconnected)? Couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For “online” you could say:

- **colligatus** (from [*colligare*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcolligo2))
- **conexus** (from [*conectere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dconecto), note: long o, single n!)

Thus for “offline” you could say:

- **incolligatus**
- **inconexus**

Or you could go a different route and say:

- **seiunctus** (from [*seiungere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dseiungo)), or alternatively:
- **disiunctus** (from [*disiungere*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Ddisiungo))

These would be technical terms describing the state of a software program or a network connection. If you want to say

> I have been offline for a week, so I don't know what cool new questions have been asked at Latin Language Beta SE.

… it would perhaps be more appropriate to say:

> **Aberam ab interreti** septem dies, ergo non novi egregia nova rogata posita apud etc.

Answer (score 5):

Great question!

One of the things I love about Latin is how it is often so much more concrete than English. Going with that, and thinking of *interrete* (internet) as a literal net, I wonder whether *intra interrete* (online) and *extra interrete* (offline) would work.

> *Per Sabbata extra rete eram, sed nunc infra sum.*

(On Saturday I was offline, but now I'm on.)

Answer (score 5):

It might be a long shot here, but I would like to suggest simply: **insum** & **absum**

This is somewhat lax/figurative usage, but this sometimes happens in other living languages, that a common word is simply adapted to denote another meaning. Not sure I'm correct here, but consider example on/off for electronic device.

Got this idea from [*ephemeris*](http://ephemeris.alcuinus.net/) site, where at the bottom you can see "nunc insunt" which would be seamlessly translated as "**online** now".

Also note that online/offline in English is adj and kind of state descriptor. it just feels to me more appropriate to use the suggested intransitive verbs [insum = I am online], rather than verbs in the passive. (In my opinion, there is slight difference between "connected" and "online").

For usage like "watch online" I would suggest: "vide **rete**(or **reti**)", which is simply the ablative case of rete.

Comment: (Hacker voice) I'm *in.* ;-)